# How to execute angular dart test in chrome in gitlab-ci

Tags: google-chrome, gitlab, gitlab-ci, angular-dart

I need to test angular dart components in chrome. Test should be executed in gitlab ci job. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achive this you can:

1. Create mew docker image with chrome and dart
2. Upload this image to [gitlab container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/)
3. Use this image in gitlab pipeline job

Here is Docker file:

```
FROM google/dart:2.5.0

USER root

# Install deps + add Chrome Stable + purge all the things
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    unzip \
    zip \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && curl -sSL https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    google-chrome-stable \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl gnupg \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir chromedriver && cd chromedriver \
    && wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && rm chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/bin/chrome
ENV CHROME_DRIVER_PATH=/chromedriver/chromedriver
```

And here is job:

```
build_web:
  stage: client_build
  image: registry.gitlab.com/your_org/your_proj/image_name
  script:
    - pub get
    - pub run build_runner test --fail-on-severe --define "build_web_compilers|entrypoint=compiler=dart2js" --delete-conflicting-outputs -- -p chrome
    - pub run build_runner build --define "build_web_compilers|entrypoint=compiler=dart2js" --delete-conflicting-outputs --output web:build
  only:
    - master
```